# Metric equivalence

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $ (X,d_1)$ and $ (Y,d_2) $ be two metric spaces. Define a one to one function 
$ f : X\to Y $. Define a new metric on $ X$ as $ d'(x_1,x_2) = d_2(f(x_1),f(x_2)) $. Question 
1) Are $ d_1 $ and $ d' $ equivalent?
2) Do $ d_1 $ and $ d' $ produce the same topology?

I know if $ d_1 $ and $ d' $ are equivalent then they produce a same topology. But I am unable to show whether they are equivalent or not.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to both of your question is: not necessarily.

Take $X=Y$ and let it be that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are metrics on $X$ that are **not** equivalent. Let $f$ be the identity on $X$. Then $d'=d_2$ so is not equivalent with $d_1$.

Comment: And to add something. If $d_1,d_2$ were equivalent then $d_1,d'$ are equivalent iff $f$ is a homeomorphism from $X\to f(X)$ at least.